# How to add a jquery plugin to angular-cli project

Tags: jquery, angular

I have already added a jquery library in to my angular-cli project but i also need to add jquery form validate plugin on the top of the jquery. I also want to integrate it with my component.ts file. how can i do this.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: you shouldn't use jQuery in angular. try using *ng-if on your div's inside your html file.

Answer (score 1):

First install jQuery using npm as follows

```
npm install jquery — save
```

Include it on your cli.json file

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

Import

```
 import * from 'jquery';
    (or)
    declare var $: any;
```

Component

```
 public ngOnInit()
  {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("someclick").click(function(){

        });
    });
  }
```